# Convert Unknown ESPG to ESPG 4326

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psycopg2, spatial-query

In running a spatial query in postgres, I got the following error:

`psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: lwgeom_intersection: GEOS Error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 676597.26377722982 3673373.5709498846 at 676597.26377722982 3673373.5709498846`

I do not know what projection is returned.  The input is all (as well as I understand it) ESPG 4326, but these are obviously not points that work in that projection.  How do I decipher what to convert from so I can locate the error?

Comment: Can you add the query that is raising the error? Have you tried `ST_SRID` to check the SRS of your geometries? https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html

Comment: Can you check if your input geometry is valid?

Answer (score 0):

The error was misreported by psycopg2 as a geometry error when it was actually a SQL error. The SQL had been changed to use a simplified polygon returned as `simple_envelope` (previously `envelope`), but the query was looking for `envelope` in some branches of a `CASE` statement.  The actual error was a missing column, but psycopg2 returned the bad geometry error with cryptic coordinates.